# Chrome Extension That Identify video in a website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a chrome extension that identify video in website like ebay , amazon and aliexpress . I tried to program making a for loop using javascript but it doesn't seem to work because it asked about permission which i don't what is it .

```js
let video  = document.getElementsByTagName('video');




for (var i = 0; i < video.length; i++){
 
 console.log( video.item(i).currentSrc)
 }
```

Comment: From the documentation, it was stated why you need to declare [permission](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/declare_permissions) for the reason to help limit damage if your extension or app is compromised by malware. Also, use the [`chrome.permissions`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/permissions) API to request [declared optional permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/permissions#manifest) at run time rather than install time, so users understand why the permissions are needed and grant only those that are necessary.

Comment: hi , do you have any idea how to write a code for this type of extension . Like i needed for personal use but i'm stuck.